# ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo ExitElement not recognized Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a Pivot page which contains two PivotItems, both are ListViews. The ListViews are both ExitElementContainers. When you click on an item in the ListView you are navigated to the item's page. So far the ContinuumNavigation works fine. If you navigate back, the navigation still works (you can see how to element "exits"). But if you go to the other ListView and do the same, the "exit animation" does not work. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Does the Transition from your second ListView work, if you only that it als ExitElementContainer (remove the attribute from the first one)?

Comment: I think the Transition traverses the Visual tree and only uses the first ExitElementContainer it finds.

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's happening. It finds the one from which I navigated first. So how can I fix it? In the Windows Store app it works without any problem.

Comment: You can just set the ExitElementContainer in the ItemClick event of the ListView (get it from the page and call [SetExitElementContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.continuumnavigationtransitioninfo.setexitelementcontainer.aspx))

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! Add your comment as the answer, so other people can see it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transition traverses the Visual tree and only uses the first *ExitElementContainer* it finds. If you have multiple ListViews, you have to set it manually in the ItemClick handler.

Get the Transition from you page and use [SetExitElementContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.continuumnavigationtransitioninfo.setexitelementcontainer.aspx).